# Importing data with nested association using Sequelize fixtures

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write an import script using [Sequelize Fixtures](https://github.com/domasx2/sequelize-fixtures) for normalized address data with the following setup:

```
const Address = sequelize.define('address', { ... });
const Cities = sequelize.define('cities', { ... });
const Regions = sequelize.define('regions', { ... });

Address.belongsTo(Cities, {
    foreignKey: 'cityId'
});

Cities.belongsTo(Regions, {
    foreignKey: 'regionId'
});
```

And below is a sample of the data I'm trying to import:

**Region import data:**

```
╔═════════════╗
║ ID  Region  ║
╠═════════════╣
║ 1   England ║
╚═════════════╝
```

**City import data:**

```
╔════════════╗
║ ID   City  ║
╠════════════╣
║ 1   London ║
╚════════════╝
```

**Address import data:**

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  Owner           Address             City    Region  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   Sherlock Holmes 221B Baker Street   London  England ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

First, I import the region data, followed by the city data with a reference to the region:

```
// regions.json
[
    {
        "model": "Regions",
        "data": {
            "label": "England"
        }
    }
]

// cities.json
[
    {
        "model": "Cities",
        "data": {
            "label": "London",
            "region": {
                "label": "England"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This works great, but is there a way to import the address data while referencing *both* the city *and* region data in order to prevent Holmes from living in London ON, CA? I've tried nesting region data inside of city:

```
// address.json
[
    {
        "model": "Address",
        "data": {
            "street_1": "221B Baker Street",
            "city": {
                "label": "London",
                "region": {
                    "label": "England"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

---

### Update #1

I tried to be clever and use [`Sequelize.literal`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/?highlight=literal#literalval-sequelizeliteral) to no avail:

```
[
    {
        "model": "Address",
        "data": {
            "street_1": "221B Baker Street",
            "cityId": {
                "val": "SELECT c.id FROM cities c LEFT JOIN regions r ON c.regionId = r.id WHERE c.label = \"London\" AND r.label = \"England\""
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've since moved on from this project (2 years already!) but a recent update on the [Github issue](https://github.com/domasx2/sequelize-fixtures/issues/63) I submitted alerted me to a response I received from the project's owner that I hadn't seen before. So in an effort to close this question and help anyone who may stumble across the issue in the future, here is [the answer](https://github.com/domasx2/sequelize-fixtures/issues/63#issuecomment-252704199):

> Haven't encountered this before. I think the only decent solution right now is to specify IDs for the cities and use those

I haven't verified the solution as, like I said, it was a long time ago and don't recall the project I was working on but let me know if it works for you!